# Backup sql server database and mail it

Tags: sql-server, email, backup, profile, jobs

I have looked and searched to find a way to backup sql server db and send the backup file to email address with sql server mail profile but i did not get it, 
I found about sending email when there is a failure in db, and other notification but i did not see about backup and sending it to email automatically, is there any way to create a job to do that ?
Thanks.

Comment: How will you mail for example 5+ GB database backup?

Comment: good question i did not mentioned that because my db size is small.

Comment: Isn't it a better option to create a shared folder in your network, place the backup there and email the path??

Comment: yes it is one of the solutions , I've wondered to see if there is a way to do with email or not. thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you double click that SQL Agent job, go to the `Steps` section add another step there and execute the following procedure there.. Also make sure the following step is executed after the database backup step.

```
Exec sp_send_dbmail   
        @profile_name =  'profile_name' 
     ,  @recipients =  'ablabla@abc.com' 
     ,  @subject =  'Database Backups bla bla'  
     ,  @body =  'body'  
     ,  @file_attachments =  'B:\Backups\DB_Back.bak'
```

This will send an email out to the person with the backup file as an attachment. Also by default sql server has a limit on how big file you can send you can change them settings to send a bigger file.

Consult your data protection team before you do this, I dont think any company would allow this to happen :) just a heads up

Comment: this is what i want thanks for your answer , i am going to test it , and don't worry about security it is for a small business there no sensitive data.